# Out of memory: Kill process (contextBroker)

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We have installed the latest version of Orion Context Broker ( 0.24 ) and execute it as a service but occasionally stops and any message appears in the log of the program.

Running dmesg we have discovered the following message:

```
[ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
[  278]     0   278     2687      116   1     -17         -1000 udevd
[  455]     0   455     2660      103   1     -17         -1000 udevd
[  742]     0   742    23294       66   0     -17         -1000 auditd
[  758]     0   758    64048     1243   0       0             0 rsyslogd
[  797]     0   797    16654      178   0     -17         -1000 sshd
[  873]     0   873    20324      227   0       0             0 master
[  886]    89   886    20386      231   1       0             0 qmgr
[  893]   497   893   160370     6803   0       0             0 mongod
[  911]     0   911    29333      161   2       0             0 crond
[  959]     0   959     1016       21   0       0             0 mingetty
[32251]   496 32251  5039887  3775085   2       0             0 contextBroker
[10052]    89 10052    20344      218   0       0             0 pickup
Out of memory: Kill process 32251 (contextBroker) score 984 or sacrifice child
Killed process 32251, UID 496, (contextBroker) total-vm:20159548kB, anon-rss:15100332kB, file-rss:8kB
```

System has 16GB of RAM.

Comment: In order to debug the problem, could you edit the question to include the following information, please? 1) the resquest messages that the CB receives since it is started until it stops, 2) how many subscriptions and registrations holds the DB, 3) operations system distribution and version, 4) tail of the /var/log/contextBroker.log file just after the fail , 5) memory consumption along time (e.g. just after starting CB, after 5 minutes, after 10 minutes, etc.) witch `ps v -p <CB_PID>`. Thanks!